# How to start fredhopper indexer and deployment agent while system start

Tags: fredhopper

To start my Fredhopper each and every time I have to execute

```
bin\deployment-agent

bin\instance indexer start
```

the above commands in command prompt. Is there any way to start the commands automatically during system start (or) during reboot?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can create a Scheduled Task (in the Windows Task Scheduler Library in Computer Management) which is configured to trigger on system startup and which doesn't require a logged in user.

Let the Task execute a batch/command file which contains those statements.